# HTML Move elements after element deleted

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As a school project I am creating an website like Google Keep where you can create and share notes. To display existing notes i use Bootstraps container, row and cards. This works fine until one element is deleted which creates a gap where the old element was. How can I remove the gap and make elements move to fill the gap?

The elements are:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,
Nikita

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here at Stack Overflow we are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to try and help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried, a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember that a large part of coding is troubleshooting and it’s important to develop this skill.

Comment: Add some of your markup and your logic for deleting elements so that we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to **not** wrap every *n* notes in a `.row` element. If you do this, the cards will reflow on their own.

Though it is hard to give a direct answer without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work from.

```js
// Demo code to illustrate card removal.
$( function () {
  
  $( '.notes' ).on( 'click', '.card', function ( e ) {
    $( this ).parent().remove();
  } );
  
} );
```

```css
.card {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container notes">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">10</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was a wrong remove-function: I deleted the card, but not the col in which it was.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things. Glad you got it working.